# ListView não carrega todos os itens

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

Estou usando ListView no meu projeto, ele estava duplicando os valores, até que coloquei o ELSE dessa condição:

```
if(convertView == null)...
else...
```

Após isso parou de duplicar, porém também parou de mostrar todos os 12 itens, agora mostrando apenas os 2 primeiros.
Alguém consegue identificar o problema?

**Informações adicionais:**
*- Cada item da lista contém 2 informações, armazenadas em ArrayList (Nome do Produto e Preço)*

Seguem códigos.

**Chamada do adapter em CarregarLista.java:**

```
ArrayList<String[]> valores = new ArrayList<String[]>();
...
//apenas para entendimento, código está ok
String tmp = nome+";"+valor;
String[] val = tmp.split(";");

valores.add(val); //valores.get(i) = Array de String [0]nome / [1]valor
Log.e("tamanho valores", String.valueOf(valores.size())); //imprime 12 (correto)

adapter = new Adaptador(CarregarLista.this, R.layout.item_lista, valores);
lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaProd);
lista.setAdapter(adapter);
...
```

**VARIÁVEIS:**
*ArrayList valores* termina o trecho de código acima com os valores:

```
ArrayList valores(12) {
    (0):  Array[0] Hamburguer 1     Array[1]R$ 14,90
    (1):  Array[0] Hamburguer 2     Array[1]R$ 16,90
    (2):  Array[0] Hamburguer 3     Array[1]R$ 14,90
    (3):  Array[0] Hamburguer 4     Array[1]R$ 16,90
    (4):  Array[0] Hamburguer 5     Array[1]R$ 14,90
    (5):  Array[0] Hamburguer 6     Array[1]R$ 16,90
    (6):  Array[0] Hamburguer 7     Array[1]R$ 14,90
    (7):  Array[0] Hamburguer 8     Array[1]R$ 16,90
    (8):  Array[0] Hamburguer 9     Array[1]R$ 14,90
    (9):  Array[0] Hamburguer 10    Array[1]R$ 16,90
    (10): Array[0] Hamburguer 11    Array[1]R$ 14,90
    (11): Array[0] Hamburguer 12    Array[1]R$ 16,90
}
```

Os únicos que são mostrados no ListView são

---

valores.get(0)[0] Hamburguer 1

valores.get(0)[1] R$ 14,90

valores.get(1)[0] Hamburguer 2

valores.get(1)[1] R$ 16,90

---

**Classe Adaptador.java que preenche o ListView:**

```
public class Adaptador extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ArrayList<String[]> valores;

    public Adaptador(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String[]> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects.get(0));
        valores = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View linha;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            linha = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista_hamburguer, parent, false);
        }else {
            linha = convertView;
            Log.e("debug", "Essa linha aparece 2x no Logcat");
        }
        Log.e("debug", "Essa linha aparece 4x no Logcat");

        TextView valor = (TextView) linha.findViewById(R.id.item_valor);
        valor.setText(valores.get(position)[1]);
        TextView nome = (TextView) linha.findViewById(R.id.item_nome);
        nome.setText(valores.get(position)[0]);

        return linha;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pelo que perces, você esta separando os itens por ponto e vírgula. Tem como você inserir também os itens aqui para que o pessoal possa tentar reproduzir seu erro?

Comment: Você diz o split com ";" ali no ArrayList valores?

Comment: sim, inserir os valores que está no ArrayList

Comment: Atualizado. Experimente comentar a parte do else que evitou a repetição dos itens, porém eu mexi em mais alguma coisa, porque o erro persiste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está passando para o `super` apenas duas `String` em `objects.get(0)`. Altere para:

```
public Adaptador(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String[]> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    valores = objects;
}
```

Perceba que no `getView` é usado `valores` mas no construtor é passado apenas duas `String`. O adaptador vai usar `getCount()` que tem a quantidade de itens em sua lista interna (como são duas `String`, `getCount()` = 2) e com isso só vai ler dois valores da lista `valores`.

Também na classe:

```
public class Adaptador extends ArrayAdapter<String>
```

Use `String[]` para o `extends`:

```
public class Adaptador extends ArrayAdapter<String[]>
```

Isso pode evitar erros futuros.

Comment: Nem imaginava o que seria haha vou testar

Comment: Perfeito! Valeu mesmo.